# SQL - Help writing query

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm sure how to do this and was looking for some help. In SQL, I need a query that goes like this Get all people Ids who's **last order date** is larger then x(a predefined date). I've tried using Max() but it doesn't seem to be working right.

thanks

Comment: It would help to describe the schema of the relevant database tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't know what the last order date is?

```
Select people_id
    , Max(Order_Date) as last_order_date
from orders_table AS O
Group By people_id
Having Max(Order_Date) > @CutOff_Date
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

SELECT ID
FROM PeopleTable
WHERE LAST_ORDER_DATE > '01-JUN-2009'

How the dates are handled depends on your RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

select * from People where lastOrderDate > @InputDate

Answer (score 1):

That actually depends on the table structure. If there is a "Last Order Date" column in the users table, then:

```
SELECT UserID
   FROM Users
   WHERE LastOrderDate > 'predefined date'
```

If you need to find it in an "orders" table, this might be correct

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID
   FROM Orders
   WHERE OrderDate > 'predefined date'
```

Or maybe if you need to take an user status into account, then...

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.UserID
   FROM Orders O
   INNER JOIN Users U ON U.UserID = O.UserID
   WHERE O.OrderDate > 'predefined date'
     AND U.UserStatus = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WHERE` clause.

[MSDN: WHERE Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course this needs more info...
Are you joining to an orders table?
Can you provide some ddl, otherwise with what you have above its quite simple:

```
SELECT blah1, blah2...FROM MyTable WHERE LastOrderDate > x
```

No seriously without more info that is what it is ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PERSON_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_DATE>DATE('2000-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work with this:

```
SELECT PeopleId FROM Orders Group By PeopleId Having Max(OrderDate)<'9/23/2009'
```